# forEach over array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Edited**

Sorry if the title is not clear enough. I really don't know how to describe what I ask for without an example.

The code is below.

Is it possible to fix this code so that I can use "normal" text for `innerHTML`? That is, labels should be as follows:

```
Dislike
Neither like nor dislike
Like
```

```js
const negative_attitude = ['dislike', 'Dislike'];
const neutral_attitude = ['neither-nor', 'Neither like nor dislike'];
const positive_attitude = ['like', 'Like'];

const radio_buttons = [negative_attitude[0], neutral_attitude[0], positive_attitude[0]];
const checked = 'neither-nor'

radio_buttons.forEach((radioButton) => {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'radio';
  input.id = radioButton.toLowerCase();
  input.name = 'attitude';
  input.value = radioButton.toLowerCase();

  if (radioButton.localeCompare(checked) === 0) {
    input.checked = true;
  }

  const label = document.createElement('label');
  label.innerHTML = radioButton; // How to fix?
  label.htmlFor = radioButton.toLowerCase();

  document.body.appendChild(input);
  document.body.appendChild(label);
});
```

Comment: Why are you adding `negative_attitude[0]` to `radio_buttons`?  Don't you want to add `negative_attitude`?  Why do you even have `radio_buttons` at all?  Why not just directly access `negative_attitude`?

Comment: You have an array where each element is a string; if you want an array of arrays you need to fix `radio_buttons` first.

Comment: Since you're putting the `[0]` element of each array into `radio_buttons` it will be `['dislike', 'neither-nor', 'like']` so you don't have an array of arrays.

Comment: @ikiK The expected values were the 2nd (`negative_attitude[1]`, etc.) values from each array.

Comment: I will edit question. Sorry, please wait for a few minutes.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sorry couple of beers in me :D Seemed right

Comment: No probs man, I agree with all of the comments above.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have edited the question. I hope now it is much clearer. Sorry that the first version was confusing and misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `radio_buttons` is not an array of arrays.  It's an array of strings.  When you use `[0]`, you are getting the 0th (starting) element of the array, so you've just added 3 strings to `radio_buttons`.

You need to *actually* make an array of arrays, by adding the *entire* arrays to `radio_buttons`.  Then when you loop over it, each element will have 2 elements (`[0]` and `[1]`) for you to work with.

```
const negative_attitude = ['dislike', 'Dislike'];
const neutral_attitude = ['neither-nor', 'Neither like nor dislike'];
const positive_attitude = ['like', 'Like'];

const radio_buttons = [negative_attitude, neutral_attitude, positive_attitude];
const checked = 'neither-nor'

radio_buttons.forEach((radioButton) => {
  const id = radioButton[0];
  const lbl = radioButton[1];

  const input = document.createElement('input');  
  input.type = 'radio';
  input.id = id;
  input.name = 'attitude';
  input.value = id;

  if (id.localeCompare(checked) === 0) {
    input.checked = true;
  }

  const label = document.createElement('label');
  label.innerHTML = lbl;
  label.htmlFor = id;

  document.body.appendChild(input);
  document.body.appendChild(label);
});
```

Comment: A small side question. I see you use `lbl` to avoid a collision with `label`. I think this is just a quick-and-dirty solution and you have a better practice to handle such cases. Maybe and underscore or something like this, that is, to replace `lbl` with `label_`?

Comment: @johnc.j. Yes, I named it `lbl`, because you already had a variable called `label`.  It's up to you how you want to name variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
radio_buttons = [negative_attitude[1], neutral_attitude[1], positive_attitude[1]];
console.log(radio_buttons);
```

Is this what you want as i made the code as far i understood what you wanted

Comment: ```console.log(radio_buttons = [negative_attitude[1], neutral_attitude[1], positive_attitude[1]]);```

Comment: No, sorry. It was my fault that the initial version of the question was confusing and misleading. It is now edited.

Answer (score 0):

**1. No need to iterate over the arrays in this case** as `radio_buttons` actually outputs as a simple array of strings containing the following:

```
['dislike', 'neither-nor', 'like']
```

You don't actually have an array of arrays in other words.

**2. Here is what you need** with different indexes on `radio_buttons` to get what you need:

```
const radio_buttons = [negative_attitude[1], neutral_attitude[1], positive_attitude[1]];
```

**3. However, as mentioned in the comments**, you might as well just hard code an array, because it makes no difference and is simpler:

```
const radio_buttons = ['dislike', 'neither-nor', 'like']
```

Comment: `negative_attitude[0]` should be `negative_attitude[1]`.

Comment: Thanks, i'll amend that now.

Comment: It was my fault that the initial version of the question was confusing and misleading. It is now edited. I cannot change `negative_attitude[0]` to `negative_attitude[1]` because the `0` elements are actually used for IDs and `1` elements are actually used for labels. If I change it in that way, I will end up with `id="neither like nor dislike"`